# The URL changes back to the previous URL after the page from the current URL is loaded

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular4-forms

First my URL IS:

```
 /pages/check_info/add_info
```

after clicking the button in that pages it loads URL:

```
/pages/check_info/add_visitor.
```

the problem is that after the form has been loaded of `add_visitor` the URL changes back to

`/pages/check_info/add_info`

but the `add_visitor` page is still there.
Now when I click a button that links back to `add_info` the button does not redirect anywhere as the current URL is the same

The code i have used for the button is

```
     <div class="btn-area">
      <button md-raised-button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded"
      type="submit">PLEASE CHECK IN</button>
      <a  routerLink='/pages/check-info/add_info'>BACK</a>
    </div>
```

The code i have used for routing:

```
 const routes: Routes = [


   {path: '',redirectTo: 'add_info', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'add_info', component: AddInfoComponent},
  {path: 'display_info', component: DisplayInfoComponent},
  {path: 'add_visitor', component: AddVisitorComponent},
  {path: 'search_student', component: SearchStudentComponent},
  {path: 'add_student', component: AddStudentComponent},
  {path: 'add_graduate', component: AddGraduateComponent},
  {path: 'check-in', component: AddInfoComponent},

];
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: use this <div class="btn-area">
      <button md-raised-button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded"
      type="submit">PLEASE CHECK IN</button>
    </div> <a  routerLink='/pages/check-info/add_info'>BACK</a> and let me know.

Comment: It still doesn't work as it still throws the same url that the page still is in

Answer (score 1):

try to change your link as follow:

```
<div class="btn-area">
      <button md-raised-button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded"
      type="submit">PLEASE CHECK IN</button>
      <a  routerLink="['/pages/check-info/add_info']">BACK</a>
    </div>
```

So change it with

```
routerLink="['/pages/check-info/add_info']"
```

Hope it helps you!

P.S it always redirect to add_info CAUSE it is the DEFAULT ROUTING ... so if it doesn't match any existing route it always redirect to it ...

If you want  a routing like yours /pages/check-info/add_info you have to do a routing with child:

so for example:

```
 {path: 'pages', component: PageComponent, 
 child[
   { path: 'check-info', component: CheckInfoComponent}
  ]},
```

and so on

Comment: It still doesn't work as it still tries to redirect to  the same url that the page still is in

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the route or the patch of code from the view. In angular if there are errors with services, packages or anything in the TS, When the path is being redirected to a page with some of these errors the page loads but the url changes back to the previous URL.